# Haskell State monad with custom fail

Tags: haskell

I want a State monad where `fail` modifies the state rather than throwing an exception.  Failure early in such an action should also skip any later actions.

For example, the following should produce `"FAILED: foo"` as the final state:

```
execState (fail "foo") ""
```

this should produce the same result

```
execState (fail "foo" >> put "hi") ""
```

Using the standard State monad, the former throws an exception and the latter produces `"hi"`

I assume there's some clever way to use `StateT` to make my own monad with this behavior, but haven't figured it out yet.  What's a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using `StateT` applied to `ErrorT` (though you may need the strict variant of `StateT` to get your desired behaviour).  Here, the `fail` call gets thrown down the stack into the next monad.

However, if you actually want it as part of the internal state rather than the stack, writing your own `State`-like monad is probably the way to go, using `Either` internally.  For example, see how [polyparse](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/polyparse/1.7/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-Poly-State.html) has a stateful parser with an internal datatype that records whether a failure has occurred or not.